# New to Bootstrap. Once Navbar has collapsed to Hamburger menu - the nav links wont drop down on click of the hamburger icon

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar

Right so, copied the standard bootstrap navbar code from both the bootstrap and the w3schools site. everything is working fine except when the navbar has collapsed to a hamburger menu nothing is displayed on click of the hamburger icon....

Even when copied and pasted with 0 edits its not working in Chrome.

Pretty sure i've properly linked all the files bootstrap needs...

Thanks for taking the time to help me out with this.

This is my complete html code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<!--    Bootstrap CSS-->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wEmeIV1mKuiNpC+IOBjI7aAzPcEZeedi5yW5f2yOq55WWLwNGmvvx4Um1vskeMj0" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    
<!-- Bootstrap Jquery files-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-lpyLfhYuitXl2zRZ5Bn2fqnhNAKOAaM/0Kr9laMspuaMiZfGmfwRNFh8HlMy49eQ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<!-- Jquery-->
<script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    
<!--Style-->
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Java-->
<script src="java.js"></script>

</head>

<body> 

<!-- Navbar-->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
<!-- Brand -->
        
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="Logo/SVG/Black Diamond - LOGO-2021_White on BG.svg" width="200">
        </a>

<!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

<!-- Navbar links -->
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Snowboards</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Men</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Women</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accesories</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You‘re using Bootstrap 4 syntax while using Bootstrap 5. Take a look at the V5 docs for a working example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. yea I thought it was something like that but I thought 4 was the newest. Regardless thanks again.